# URL not found when page refresh after deploying angular application to server

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created an application in angular and deployed the build files in a shared hosting. The application is running fine in server but when I am refreshing the page (Ex: /login) it always returns 404 page not found.

I have used the command ng build --prod --build-optimizer to generate build. My main domain is **http://rahuls.co.in**. And in my hosting I have created one folder pawsticks which contains all the build files and I have created a subdomain to point that folder. Subdomain is **https://pawsticks.rahuls.co.in**.

**public_html -> pawsticks  -->  https://pawsticks.rahuls.co.in**

Please suggest what should I do to fix this 404 error when refresh this **https://pawsticks.rahuls.co.in/login**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#` mechanism

Do these

1-import the below two modules from `“@angular/common”` like below in the `“app.module.ts”` file

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy  } from '@angular/common';
```

2- In same file (`app.module.ts`) in providers array add this below line

```
 providers: [
    {provide : LocationStrategy , useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
    ],
```

Compile build and redeploy

Comment: If I use this, is it going to add a # in the url?

Comment: Yes ,that will add .Otherwise you have to modify the server configuration you are using to serve your application ,thats actually pretty complicated. This one is the easiest @SwagataAdhikary

Comment: Can be able to share what are the configurations i need to make if I want to run it without #

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: Then its not possible ,you need to have root access to change the server configurations @SwagataAdhikary .You have to use the # strategy only